# Free Open Source Filtering & Sorting Bootstrap Table

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, sorting

Does anybody have advice on free open source plug-ins for use with Bootstrap tables that allow a user to search/filter and sort data? DataTables isn't free anymore.

We have a few apps that use bootstrap so it will keep the same feel as everything else if we stick with it here.

This is for use with a simple inventory management project, where one workflow is for a user to search their inventory for an item, and check the checkbox in the data row to add it to the selection. They then choose the state to apply to the status selected from a drop down to all selected items. I have ajax handler that gets all the selected items json.stringingy's them, and sends to an web service API.

Based on the customer requirements they may need to search for an item name or type, Or they may need to sort by date or quantity. They may also need to to have the data sorted and filtered at the same time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this plugin](http://holt59.github.io/datatable/) could fullfill your requirements.

Hope I could help with my answer. :)

Comment: That does the trick for me. I guess the DataTables owner came in and down-voted everything as soon as you answered.

Comment: The demo works and the documentation is good enough. I haven't implemented it with my project yet, but it answers my question. No promises that someone won't come with something better later, since I mentioned date sorting and this forces me to use a "yyyy-MM-dd HH-mm-ss" format to get it sorted properly.

Comment: Thats nice, that you are satisfied now :)